# Display Hyperlink Hand Cursor for Check Box on MS Access Form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

How do I make check boxes in an ms access report have a hyperlink hand on hover?

```
If cc.ControlType = acCheckBox Then
    'cc.DisplayAsHyperlink = acDisplayAsHyperlinkAlways
    ' cc.IsHyperlink = True
    'cc.CursorOnHover = acCursorOnHoverHyperlinkHand
End If
```

But I get this error:

[image: Object doesn't support this property or method]

Comment: As far as I can tell, the Access CheckBox object does not have the `CursorOnHover`, `DisplayAsHyperlink`, or `IsHyperlink` properties. Thus the error. You might be able to force a fix for this, but may I humbly suggest that it isn't worth your time? Instead, use a Hyperlink object to manage your links.

Comment: I want the hyperlink had to indicate to the use "hey this object does something"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CursorOnHover is a property for CommandButton objects. A simple work-around would be to place a transparent button behind your check boxes and set the CursorOnHover property to acHyperlink hand from the Property Sheet.

Comment: I tested this, and it doesn't work for me. The CommandButton 'Hyperlink Hand' cursor only shows when over parts of the command button that are *not* covered by the CheckBox. The cursor reverts back to normal when it is over the CheckBox. YMMV.

Comment: Put the invisible CommandButton over the CheckBox. Write vba for the OnClick of the CommandButton that checks the current state of the CheckBox and then changes it. Then you can have your cursor and the CheckBox as you want.

Comment: @JennyW: That's a whole lot of extra work for no tangible gain. For example, I have 904 CheckBox controls in one project I work with. Do I really want to add 904 CommandButtons and 904 event handlers, just to put up a non-standard cursor? No! This marginal idea doesn't justify this amount of complexity!

Comment: Fair enough- it’s not an option in that situation, i agree. It is an option for anyone who only needs it one or two places, and the op seems to be.

Comment: @kismert: In a situation like that, I think you could also write a VBA sub to search all forms / reports / objects in the current project folder for all objects on them to begin with and then have it place a transparent CommandButton over each of them with the same length and width, top and left dims as the CheckBox. You could then add in the suggestion from JennyW regarding the OnClick event when the CommandButtons are generated.

Comment: @Phenide: Can you do that? Yes. Should  you do it? I see no valid argument. I am fully able to write the complex code to automate adding complexity to every form that has a CheckBox. What is the result? 99% of users would never notice it. This is effort that would be much better spent (for example) by adding comprehensive error handling, or formal transactions for all data operations.

Comment: @kismert I understand that. I was just providing a solution to the expanded problem you had described as framed in the context of the initial question (regardless of whether a user would notice or not). By all means I can understand effort being better used elsewhere, but in context of the initial question, the ability to expand some solution to a wider scope seems reasonable to propose. By all means I do appreciate the perspective you provide though, as it is understandable and I am new to the world of development in any context. Thank you for your comments and have a great day!